# magit with tramp is slow

Tags: magit, tramp, performance

Here is my environment:

- project A is on the server. My PC connects to the server by 1 Gbit ethernet. Ping latency between PC and server are about 0.3 ms.
- project A's source code size is about 75 MB. But its ".git" directory is about 800 MB.

My magit is quite slow. Run magit checkout to another branch (with nothing different between these 2 branches) in project A could take as long as 25 seconds.

Here is my profiling info for checkout to branch:
  [image: Profiling Informantion]

I've checked the performance tips in magit [doc](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/MacOS-Performance.html#MacOS-Performance) and tried it, but no obvious improvement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try to dig deeper into this problem by setting `(setq tramp-verbose 10)`.

Here is one possible step for reproducing the slowness:

- `git clone https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-hotspot.git` on server A and create a `test` branch base on `master` branch.
- using tramp to visit a file in above project
- run `magit-checkout test`

And find the slowness is caused by that tramp tries to find the end of remote command's output by searching some pattern in `tramp-wait-for-output` function's line `(tramp-wait-for-regexp proc timeout regexp1)`. In this case:

- `regexp1` is `"\\(^\\|\000\\)[^#$\n]*///deab18b5e34aa7487addb2439bbab2a9#\\$\r?$"`
- `proc`'s buffer string is the output of command: `git "--no-pager" "--literal-pathspecs" "-c" "core.preloadindex=true" ls-tree -z -r --name-only HEAD` in above git repository. Which is one quite huge line. In my test case, it is a line with `226383` character and split by null. Here is part of it: `.hgignore^@.hgtags^@.jcheck/conf^@ASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION^@LICENSE^@README^@`
- `timeout` argument is `nil`

So I walk around this issue by modifying `tramp-check-for-regexp` to below:

```
(defun tramp-check-for-regexp (proc regexp)
  "Check, whether REGEXP is contained in process buffer of PROC.
Erase echoed commands if exists."
  (with-current-buffer (process-buffer proc)
    (if (> (point-max) 1000)
        (progn
          (goto-char (point-max))
          (ignore-errors (re-search-backward regexp (- (point-max) 1000) t)))
      (progn
        (goto-char (point-min))

        ;; Check whether we need to remove echo output.
        (when (and (tramp-get-connection-property proc "check-remote-echo" nil)
                   (re-search-forward tramp-echoed-echo-mark-regexp nil t))
          (let ((begin (match-beginning 0)))
            (when (re-search-forward tramp-echoed-echo-mark-regexp nil t)
              ;; Discard echo from remote output.
              (tramp-set-connection-property proc "check-remote-echo" nil)
              (tramp-message proc 5 "echo-mark found")
              (forward-line 1)
              (delete-region begin (point))
              (goto-char (point-min)))))

        (when (or (not (tramp-get-connection-property proc "check-remote-echo" nil))
                  ;; Sometimes, the echo string is suppressed on the remote side.
                  (not (string-equal
                        (tramp-compat-funcall
                         'substring-no-properties tramp-echo-mark-marker
                         0 (min tramp-echo-mark-marker-length (1- (point-max))))
                        (tramp-compat-funcall
                         'buffer-substring-no-properties
                         (point-min)
                         (min (+ (point-min) tramp-echo-mark-marker-length)
                              (point-max))))))
          ;; No echo to be handled, now we can look for the regexp.
          ;; Sometimes, lines are much to long, and we run into a "Stack
          ;; overflow in regexp matcher".  For example, //DIRED// lines of
          ;; directory listings with some thousand files.  Therefore, we
          ;; look from the end.
          (goto-char (point-max))
          (ignore-errors (re-search-backward regexp nil t)))))))
```

I add checking whether the buffer is larger than 1000 point, if yes, add "bound" to `re-search-backward` and ignore other checking and processing. This is really a dirty hack without any considering of other case using `tramp-check-for-regexp`.

However, it reduces the `magit-checkout` time from `25s` to `3s`.

Hope tramp could fix this issue in the future.

Comment: Rather than hope, better `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, most of the time is spent in `tramp-check-for-regexp`. This is, where the output of the remote processes, magit has fired, is parsed. Don't know how to improve there from user side.

In Tramp 2.3.2, which will be released next two days, there are some changes in this corner. Most important, while reading output from external processes, running timers are discarded. I have no hard figures, but I believe this might increase performance. Maybe you give this Tramp version a try.

Comment: I have looked into a similar issue a long time ago and it did indeed turn out that some regexp inefficiency in tramp was the culprit. When magit requests a list of files from git, it requests them to be separated with null characters. This can result in very long lines, which is a problem because tramp (if I remember correctly) looks for some information that is usually found at the very beginning of a line by searching from the very end of every line. I hope that's one of the things that was changed!

Comment: The last time this issue came up, the solution for that particular user was to setup good git ignore rules to prevent a very long line listing thousands of untracked files.

Comment: No, there wasn't done something with respect to regexp parsing in Tramp recently. Just some changes when and how timers are invoked (which could run long time also). Honestly, I'm not a magit user, but maybe I shall try this in order to reproduce the problem. Are there special magit settings or examples which would trigger the problem prominently?

Comment: Hi, Michael, here is the step to reproduce this issue:

Comment: There is no special set up for reproducing this issue. I use magit on hotspot project. It can be downloaded by: git clone "hg::http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/hs/hotspot/". It is a hg project. I clone it by git. To make git be able to clone hg repo, you should have mercurial installed and put  git-remote-hg (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/felipec/git-remote-hg/master/git-remote-hg) to your $PATH directory.

Comment: @MichaelAlbinus, I've checked with latest tramp master branch. There is not much performance improvement. Most of the time is also spent at `tramp-check-for-regexp`.

Comment: I want to reproduce the problem, but I cannot get your project. I get the response `ERROR: repository hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/hs/hotspot/ not found`

Comment: @MichaelAlbinus, Sorry for the inconvenience. The issue could also be reproduced by this similar project: `https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-hotspot.git`

Comment: I could clone this repository, and in Emacs I could call `magit-status` That's it. Since I'm not a magit user, could you pls give some short commands how I could continue in order to see the problem? And no, I don't intend to learn magit these days; I haven't enough time for this.

Comment: @MichaelAlbinus, sorry for no response (stackexchange seems not notify new comment). Following is the step to see the problem: 1. say you are on master branch on hotspot project, run: `git checkout -b test` in a shell to create a new test branch and check out to it 2. then run `magit-checkout master` in emacs. That's it.

Comment: @MichaelAlbinus, could also take a look at my new added answer and will you fix this issue in tramp?