# When editing remotely, after I change the working tree with magit, why won't my buffers autorevert?

Tags: magit, tramp

I have magit autorevert set (and also global autorevert), and it seems to work OK editing local files but not using tramp over ssh.  If I do, say, a hard reset in magit, my buffers aren't autoreverted, and I have to run revert-buffer manually.

Comment: Could it be that it's autoreverting, just slowly? See https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Performance.html#Performance and https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/33845/magit-with-tramp-is-slow/34686

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely, you must set `auto-revert-remote-files` to a non-nil value.